# jquery not submitting form data

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I not good with jQuery but i try and try. I am trying to submit a multipart form with the following code but i can't seem to get the form data. I tried

HTML

```
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="form">
<input type="text" name="somename" value="24" />
<input type="file" name="fill"  />
<input type="submit" value="Save" name="sub" />     
</form>
<span id="showmsg"></span>
```

JavaScript:

```
$(function(){
    $("#form").on('click',function(e) {
    $.ajax({
        url:'ajax.php',
        data:new FormData(this),
        type:'POST',
        contentType:false,
        cache:false,
        processData:false,
        success:function(data){
        $("#showmsg").show().html(data);
        },
    });
    e.preventDefault(); 
 });        
});
```

doesn't work, i have tried

```
$("#form").submit(function(e) {
$("#form").on('submit',function(e) {
```

Comment: Any error in browser console?

Comment: none, but i am able to get a value that i echo out on the ajax.php page, but i can't see the form data

Comment: have a look at my fiddle

Comment: If you used .submit, you should have had a working example.. Is the data itself being sent from the form..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jyqae801/2/

I've change the form event for the .submit one

```
$(function(){

    $("#form").submit(function( event ) {
        $.ajax({
            url:'ajax.php',
            data: new FormData(this),
            type:'POST',
            contentType:false,
            cache:false,
            processData:false,
            success:function(data){
                $("#showmsg").show().html(data);
            },
        });
        alert('form has been submitted');
        event.preventDefault(); 
    });        
});
```

You can also replace

```
new FormData(this)
```

With

```
$( "#form" ).serialize()
```

As i am not sure if "this" would be in the scope of the ajax or form.. honestly have not tested recently so memory is not so good on it.

I personally use something like this BUT i think in your case of files will need some adjusting: http://jsfiddle.net/5f9wekLn/

Form

```
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="form">
    <input type="text" name="somename" value="24" />
    <input type="file" name="fill"  />
    <input type="button" value="Save" id="save" name="sub" />     
</form>
<span id="showmsg">.....waiting......</span>
```

JS

```
$(function(){


    $("#save").click(function(e){
        $("#showmsg").html("submitting form");
        $.post("ajax.php",$("#form" ).serialize())
        .done(function(data){
            $("#showmsg").html("server response: " + data);
        })
        .fail(function(){
            $("#showmsg").html("server fail");
        });
        e.preventDefault(); 
    });


});
```

Comment: nothing, for some reason i can't seem to post the data, i check the console log, it sees the page but no error.